# Pass argument to custom permision class in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-permissions

I have a custom permission class that extends the rest framework base permission. I am trying to pass an argument `allowed_groups` that will be a list of all the groups that have access to the particular view.

This is my current custom permission implementation.

```
class CustomUserPermisions(BasePermission): 
    
    message = "Ooops! You do not have permissions to access this particular site"
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        allowed_groups = [ 'group_hr', 'super_admin', 'employee']
        user1 = Employee.objects.filter(user__email=request.user).first()
        user_groups = user1.user_group.all()
        for group in user_groups:
            if group.title in allowed_groups:
                return True 
        return False
```

I have tried adding an argument as follows.

```
class CustomUserPermisions(BasePermission, allowed_groups): 
    
    message = "Ooops! You do not have permissions to access this particular site"
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        allowed_groups = [ 'group_hr', 'super_admin', 'employee']
        user1 = Employee.objects.filter(user__email=request.user).first()
        user_groups = user1.user_group.all()
        for group in user_groups:
            if group.title in allowed_groups:
                return True 
        return False
```

but this is the error I am currently receiving.

```
class CustomUserPermisions(BasePermission, allowed_groups):
```

> NameError: name 'allowed_groups' is not defined

Is there a better way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are a newcomer to python.
You should read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html to get better understanding about python classes.

`class CustomUserPermisions(BasePermission, allowed_groups):`
means that the class `CustomUserPermisions` inherits from the classes `BasePermission` and `allowed_groups`. `allowed_groups` is not a class, so you get an error.

You should create a class attribute for allowed group :

```
class CustomUserPermisions(BasePermission):
    def __init__(self, allowed_groups):
        self.allowed_groups = allowed_groups
        self.message = "Ooops! You do not have permissions to access this particular site"

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        user1 = Employee.objects.filter(user__email=request.user).first()
        user_groups = user1.user_group.all()
        for group in user_groups:
            if group.title in self.allowed_groups:
                return True
        return False
```

and then call the class constructor :

`permissions = CustomUserPermisions(['group_hr', 'super_admin', 'employee'])`